# Echoing to a file results in spaces in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, spaces

Using a batch file (.bat), I'm making a script that requires dynamic paths so that it can work on multiple computers. My problem is when I echo something to a file, it adds a line and an a return carriage.

Say I have a text file named `foo.txt` in the directory of the batch file, and its contents are completely empty.

In the batch file, I run:

```
echo test > foo.txt
```

The contents of `foo.txt` will be:

```
L1: foo

L2:
```

There would be a space after `foo` in the first line and a second empty line. Now, this would be completely okay and I would entirely ignore it, but filename paths do not ignore it.

importing text from foo.txt like so:

```
set /p foo=< foo.txt
```

...and then:

```
set /p name=< C:\A.D.V.E.N.T.U.R.E.\test\%foo%\test2.txt
```

...would be interpreted as:

```
set /p name=< C:\A.D.V.E.N.T.U.R.E.\test\foo \test2.txt
```

Including an unwanted space. Is there anyway to make it so you can write text to a file without a space, or a command one could use to delete the carriage return and the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data should be `test`, not `foo`

Clasically, try

```
>foo.txt echo test
```

but make sure that there are no trailing spaces after `test`.

(to APPEND to `foo.txt` use `>>` in place of `>`)

Comment: Thanks! Although it still did insert a carriage return, the space is now gone!

Comment: Note also that `echo test>foo.txt` would work just as well.  To get rid of the space, you just ... well, get rid of the space!

Comment: Ah, true, @harry - but it fails to produce the complete string if the string to be echoed terminates with a digit, whereas the `>file echo something` does.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use parentheses to make sure unwanted space is not included in the output:

```
(echo test)      >foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

above given answers works.
But, the actual reason I found for it was the space before `>`
So, instead of

```
echo test > foo.txt
```

it must be

```
echo test> foo.txt
```

NOTE. Don't put any space between test and >. This, results in a trailing space.